# Assigning the result of Perl regex operation to a second variable

Tags: regex, perl

Can the following Perl code be simplified into one statement:

my $a = 'hello';
my $b = $a;
$b =~ s/o//;

I am looking for something like:

$b = $a =~ s/o//;

(although that does not produce what I want; $b becomes "1" or "true")

Comment: You shouldn't `my` the special sorting variables `$a` and `$b`.

Answer (score 6):

Close; you need some extra parentheses, because `=` is lower precedence than most operators.

```
($b = $a) =~ s/o//;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
( $b = $a ) =~ s/o//;
```